# Is the new ART a virtual machine?

Tags: android, virtual-machine, dalvik

I have read through articles on the internet about the new ART runtime for the Android operating system. Many of the articles call ART a new virtual machine, which I think is wrong because applications are fully compiled upon installation to native machine code. If ART is not a virtual machine, what does it do then? Does it provide a runtime environment such as a garbage collector, a memory manager etc to the running applications?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the ART is a virtual machine even though applications are fully compiled to native machine code.

To over simplify:

The ART itself is as an Android application that simulates the hardware (CPU, registers, etc.) of an imaginary machine with a CPU that has a machine code instruction set consisting of byte-code.

Android programs (APKs) are compiled into the byte-code instructions that are executed by this virtual machine program.

The virtual machine (ART) is implemented by a native-code program (i.e., a program executed by the hardware CPU). Each byte-code instruction for the virtual machine has corresponding native code that implements the virtual machine operation and changes the state of the virtual machine. So, for example, a byte-code instruction to load a register does not necessarily result in the loading of a hardware register. Instead it results in the native-code program (ART) performing operations that represent loading a virtual machine register (perhaps loading a memory location instead of a hardware register).

When interpretation is used, the native-code program implementing the virtual machine retrieves a byte-code instruction and decodes the byte-code to determine which set of native code instructions to execute to put the virtual machine into the state required by the byte-code instruction.

When the byte-code is compiled into native code (just-in-time or ahead-of-time), the byte-code decoding step is eliminated. Instead, the byte-code instructions for the virtual machine are replaced by the native-code that implement the virtual machine operations.

That is, instead of the APK consisting of a sequence of byte-code instructions it now consists of a sequence of ART native code instructions that represent state changes required by the byte code.

The key point is that even though the byte-code is no longer being processed, the virtual machine (ART) is still the program being executed on hardware, not the APK program.

Answer (score 2):

> Does it provide a runtime environment such as a garbage collector, a memory manager etc to the running applications?

Yes, plus hooks for debugging and tracing, and probably more. Note that there is a Google I|O 2014 conference presentation coming up that will go into more details (presumably).

> Many of the articles call ART a new virtual machine, which I think is wrong because applications are fully compiled upon installation to native machine code.

[Google describes it as a "runtime"](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/art.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you mean ART is a Virtual Machine in a sense that it 'sandbox' the process and resources, I think it has the same limitations as Dalvik Machine (because the DEX code is converted to Native Code) and the programming interfaces like content providers etc. are still used to access data. GC is not particular to a Virtual Machine, Native Windows applications in C++ can be written with a custom garbage collector as required.